# Check if mysql mode have STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My app (LAMP Stack) often get "no default value"-error due to different mysql environment. So, I guess I want to check if mysql have the mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` enabled or not, then warn the user. But I dont know how.

**How to check if mysql mode have STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from PHP ?**

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't you agree that `DEFAULT` is a sign of short-cut programming? Essentially not caring how you program

Comment: @Drew .. this is just workaround for my old app, can't set default value for each column. I prefer to use `DEFAULT` for new version. :)